# How to update event time in Django model?

Tags: python, django

I have the following code. The expect outcome would be:

1. If the event does not exist, then the admin form shows only created_at time, the updated_at field is empty.
2. If the event exists:
   a. if there is no updated_at, the field would be filled with time now.
   b. if updated_at exists, the field time should be updated.

My code does not work, how should I change it? Thank you.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
import uuid


class Venue (models.Model):




class Types(models.TextChoices):
    LPN='LPN',
    RN ='RN'

type = models.CharField(
    max_length=3,
    choices=Types.choices,
    default=Types.RN
)
venue_id= models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=True,null=True, blank=True) 


if venue_id is True:

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=True,null=True,   blank=True)
    updated_at.update()

else:
    
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None, editable=True,null=True, blank=True)

place_text=models.CharField(max_length=200)


date = models.DateField ('Date')
start_time = models.DateTimeField ('start time')
finish_time= models.DateTimeField ('finish time')
details= models.CharField (max_length=500)

def _str_(self):
    return self.venue_text
```

please refer to the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic like this should be done via signal.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#post-save

If you specify logic on model like this it does not register changes.

Redefine your models with all field you want it to have, if you want
update_at field to be null upon creation, until it actually gets
updated go with default=None, otherwise you can use auto_now.

If you want certain action to happen after you edit any field or so,
go with signals.

Comment: Thanks @David. I would like to get more comments from the others as well. I 'm not so familiar with signal. But I will read it

Comment: Kind off simplified version: 

You prepare model as it is, then in the app folder you create signals.py 

Define your post_save methods. They work as they sound, you want something to happen after something has changed.

Then you need to add them to apps.py in your appconfig. 

def ready(self):
    import app_name.signals

Comment: Tks @David Roucka. I did something a little bit simpler. (ref. to my answer hereinbelow). But it has a problem that when user inputs the events for the first time, the froms shows also updated time even it shouldn't. Otherwise, it's ok. Any comments? Tks.

Comment: I honestly don't know right now without testing and I'm pretty busy with work now. 
I think you should do if / if not conditions in the signal which would set values depending on objects condition for the desired values.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.dispatch import receiver  

from django.db.models.signals import (

    pre_save,
    post_save

    )
 # Create your models here.

class Venue (models.Model):

    class Types(models.TextChoices):
        LPN='LPN',
        RN ='RN'

type = models.CharField(
    max_length=3,
    choices=Types.choices,
    default=Types.RN
)

created = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=True,null=True, blank=True) 
updated = models.DateTimeField(default=None, editable=True,null=True, blank=True)

date = models.DateField ('Date')
start_time = models.DateTimeField ('start time')
finish_time= models.DateTimeField ('finish time')
details= models.CharField (max_length=500)
place_text=models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.place_text


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Venue)
def venue_pre_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

    #instance.updated =None
    instance.updated=timezone.now()

@receiver(post_save, sender=Venue)
def venue_post_save(sender, instance,created, *args, **kwargs):

    if created:

        instance.updated=timezone.now()
        instance.save()
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain to OP how this code answers the question

Comment: @OsVoid, I asked the question and got advice from DavidRouchcka, to reply his last comment, I added my code in the answer.